# how to prove that the cantor set has Lebesgue measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis

mate how do you prove that the set of cantor has Lebesgue measure zero?

the Cantor set is defined as an intersection of other sets (in which you are removing thirds). The Lebesgue measure satisfies that if $A\subset B$, then the measure of $A$ is less than that of $B$.

Since Cantor is the intersection of all these sets, then its measure is less than any of them. Well, with this in mind, the idea is to find the measures of these sets and see that they go to zero.

Comment: Do you have problems finding the measure of $[0,1]$? How about the measure of $[0.1/3]\cup[2/3,1]$???

Answer (score 1):

Call $C_0=[0,1]$, $C_1=[0,\frac 13]\cup[\frac 23, 1]$, $C_2=[0,\frac 19]\cup[\frac 29,\frac 13]\cup[\frac 23,\frac 79]\cup[\frac 89,1]$  and so on… In this way, you have that the Cantor set is just $\bigcap_i C_i$, where, for each $i$, $C_i$ is the disjoint union of $2^i$ intervals of measure $3^{-i}$, and that $C_{i+1}\subset C_i$. Then the measure of the Cantor set is equal to $\inf_i |C_i|= \inf_i \frac {2^i}{3^i}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The complement of the Cantor set has measure $$\dfrac 13\sum_{n\ge0}\dfrac {2^n}{3^n}=\dfrac 13\dfrac 1{1-\dfrac 23}=1$$, by construction.   Therefore the measure is $m(\mathcal C)=m([0,1])-1=1-1=0$.

Comment: Thanks, very much